# Given a json and dictionary with keys and subkeys in string format, create a copy of the json with only key-values in the dict

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a set of json with different levels of data but similar structures. I have a file with the values that are relevant, in format similar to the example.

```
full_json = {"a": {"a1": 4, "a2": 5}, "b": 2, "c": 3}
relevant_keys = ["['a']['a1']", "['b']"]
```

I want to create a copy of the json, only with the relevant key-value pairs

```
expected_json = {"a": {"a1": 4}, "b": 2}
```

How can I do it programmatically so I can keep adding values in `relevant_keys`, and extract different data in different levels?
Deleting is not an option, as the json might have new fields, not relevant for my use case.

Comment: Can you change the relevant keys to lists of keys instead of strings? Then you can loop through them, indexing the dictionary.

Comment: It would be easier if it were `[['a', 'a1'], ['b']]`

Comment: This is too broad for a simple, definitive answer.  The given problem requires you to parse each element of your relevant keys, extracting those values so that you can apply them to the dict and extract the desired output.  This is covered in a variety of other places.

Comment: I am given the `relevant_keys` in the format above. I could create a manual list as last resource, however I have several files with relevant keys and the json are >15MB, so I am trying to automate as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I used dynamic evaluation of strings:

- Access to the value of the `full_json` via `eval(f'full_json{k}')`
- Make string pattern with placeholder, then perform the substitution. I did it with the old `%` (just because I was lazy) but it can be re implemented with `format` but then you should escape the `{,}`. Furthermore the `tuple` casting is needed for `%` otherwise just `*`the list.

```
full_json = {"a": {"a1": 4, "a2": 5}, "b": 2, "c": 3}
relevant_keys = ["['a']['a1']", "['b']"]

expected_json = {}
for k in relevant_keys:

    # clean string
    k_ids = k[1:-1].replace('][', ' ').split()  # slice rm the open&close bracket
    # dictionary pattern with placeholder
    k_ids_str = '{%s: ' * len(k_ids) + '%s' + '}' * len(k_ids)
    # populate the string-like dictionary
    k_dict_cmd = k_ids_str % tuple(k_ids + [eval(f'full_json{k}')])
    # evaluate the pattern and update the needed dictionary
    expected_json.update(**eval(k_dict_cmd))


print(expected_json)
```

Output

```
{'a': {'a1': 4}, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: the ```format``` implementation is still lacking I will be very curious to see it!